# Vue JS - Loop through nested object without knowing its name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, axios, lodash

I perform an axios call which returns the following (example):

```
{
   "data":{
      "xyz":[
         {
            "foo":1234,
            "baz":5678,
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have a `.then()` in my axios call where I use lodash to `_.cloneDeep` my `response.data` (above) to a data property in my vue instance.

What is the right way to do a `v-for` on `xyz` without knowing it's name (it can be different)? Or how do I directly clone `xyz` to my data property?

Comment: you can use Object.keys(data) and then get by key or simply Object.values(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly clone `xyz` to your data property, you can just do (assuming `response.data` contains that snippet that you gave in your question:

```js
dataPropertyInVueInstance = response.data["data"][Object.keys(response.data["data"])[0]]
```

This gets the first key at `response.data["data"]` (in this case, `xyz`) and pulls the data there out of `response.data["data"]`, thus giving you the object at `xyz` and avoiding the naming issue.

You could also do:

```js
dataPropertyInVueInstance = Object.values(response.data["data"])[0]
```

This gets the value at the first key in `response.data["data"]` -- in this case, the data at key `xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just nest v-for:

```
<div v-for="(item,key) in data" :key="key"> 
     <div v-for="(nestedItem, nestedKey) in item)" :key="nestedKey">
         {{ nestedItem }}
     </div>
</div>
```